# Cannot find the member on target type in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a custom routedcommand in my WPF app. So far, I have this in my namespace named `ffodle`

```
public static class TestCommands
    {
        public static RoutedCommand mycommand = new RoutedCommand("MyCommand", typeof(TestCommands));
        public static RoutedCommand MyCommand { get { return mycommand; } }
    }
```

And in my xaml, I have `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ffodle"` in the `window` tag.

and then right below the `window` tag I have

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:TestCommands}" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

When I'm typing the `x:static local:` part out, it suggests to me `App`, `MainWindow`, and `TestCommands` but no matter what I've tried and the tutorial I'm following, does it exactly like this. I've also tried clearing the cache of VS as someone suggested in another post, but it still says it cannot find the member on the target type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the class `static`?

Comment: It was part of the tutorial I was following. I'm quite new to C#.

Comment: If the tutorial you are following uses `static` with such reckless abandon, then my suggestion to you would be to find some other tutorial.

Comment: There's very little on RoutedCommands without a ton of overhead for one custom command and that one was the most dumbed down. I'm just wanting to use a key bind to run a function

Comment: @MikeNakis Should we also find some other micr0s0ft? See [ApplicationCommands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) which is a `static` class too

Comment: @ErraticFox Can you please describe what the real problem is? I have no problems to use such routed commands, but my xaml looks in the end like `<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:TestCommands.MyCommand}" />`. Is it really that you miss that `MyCommand` in the end?

Comment: @ErraticFox BTW: You should never use `public` fields. And in this special case it would be more than enough to have `public static RoutedCommand MyCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand( "MyCommand", typeof( TestCommands ) );`

Answer (score 0):

`TestCommands` is the type. You should set the `Command` property to an `ICommand` member of the type. This works for me:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:TestCommands.MyCommand}" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```